# How to find and replace any characters between 2nd comma and 4th comma in a string using regex

Tags: regex

I have a csv file which contains many lines of string like this:

```
001,bbb,002,ddd,eee,fff
```

I'd like to change it to:

```
001,bbb,eee,fff
```

using find/replace and regex

what is the right regex for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find what:

```
^([^,]*,[^,]*),[^,]*,[^,]*,
```

OR

```
^([^,]*,[^,]*),\d+,[^,]*,
```

Replace with:

```
\1,
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dN1xI0/3)

Comment: thanks Avinash Raj, you solution works only if there's no digit. actually in my case, there are numbers in the strings.

Comment: sorry i don't know what you mean. It works for any character. could you provide an example where the above regex would fail?